# NInject WCF extension not working with ninject 2.3

Tags: ninject, ninject-extensions

I was using NInject WCF extension 2.2 in my application, but after upgrading the Ninject version to 2.3, it stops working and return some serialization error. Is there any upgraded version of WCF extension for 2.3 or i've to use Ninject 2.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ninject 2.3 is not a released version. It requires Ninject.Extensions.WCF 2.3 found at github or on the build server teamcity.codebetter.com

Comment: Hi, please give me the link, i am unable to find it. Many Thanks Sir

Comment: @MSingh: Please provide some indication as to how or where you've looked. Are you seeing the wrong version? Not seeing extensions? Going to the wrong site?

Comment: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf,, The version here available for download is 2.2.0.0 and this gives me serialization exception with ninject 2.3.

Comment: @MSingh: But he said "found at github or on the build server teamcity.codebetter.com". The source is at github, and you can compile it. HTTP:// teamcity.codebetter.com is a build server from which you can download lots of precompiled editions of it - give it a try.